# How to get a table into a subclass?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, class

im having some trouble here,

my class is as follows:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ITAPP.Models
{
    public class Quote
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string QuoteNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PartNo { get; set; }
    }
    public class Supplier
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TelNo { get; set; }
    }
    public class QuoteViewModel
    {
        public Quote Quote { get; set; }
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my query is as follows:-

```
var result = db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers
            .Include(tbl => tbl.tblItems)
            .Include(tbl => tbl.tblQuotes)
            .Include(tbl => tbl.tblSuppliers).GroupBy(tbl => new { tbl.tblQuotes, tbl.tblSuppliers, tbl.tblItems })
            .Select(grouped => new QuoteViewModel
            {
                Quote = grouped.Key.tblQuotes,
                Supplier = grouped.Key.tblSuppliers,
                Item = grouped.Key.tblItems,
                Quantity = grouped.Sum(tbl => tbl.Quantity),
                Price = grouped.Sum(tbl => tbl.Price)
            });
```

when i try put a table into a subclass (i.e tblQuotes into Quote) i get "Cannot Convert ITAPP.Models.tblQuotes to ITAPP.Models.Quote"

if i type a dot after grouped.key.tblQuotes i get the fields from tblQuotes

im not sure how i get the table into the subclass?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
var result = db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers
            .Include(tbl => tbl.tblItems)
            .Include(tbl => tbl.tblQuotes)
            .Include(tbl => tbl.tblSuppliers)
            .GroupBy(tbl => new { tbl.tblQuotes,tbl.tblSuppliers, tbl.tblItems })
            .Select(grouped => new QuoteViewModel
            {
                Quote = new Quote{ID=grouped.Key.tblQuotes.ID,
                                  QuoteNo =grouped.Key.tblQuotes.QuoteNo ,
                                  Date= grouped.Key.tblQuotes.Date},
                Supplier = grouped.Key.tblSuppliers,
                Item = grouped.Key.tblItems,
                Quantity = grouped.Sum(tbl => tbl.Quantity),
                Price = grouped.Sum(tbl => tbl.Price)
            });
```